# What's the difference in these two shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, r

I'm trying to plot points on [these](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wimca0c126966bq/AABOTzj9RW_JFiz-ZvGoHiy6a) maps in R, with points from "Coordinates" in the same folder.

The WL.shp plots fine with the data, but the NG.shp (which should only be larger and of the same area + surroundings) won't show the dots?

I tried different UTM zones and GIS programs (MapInfo and QGIS).
Can anyone help to what the issue is, what am I missing to make this work?

```
## appropriate library. 
library(StatDA)
library(rgdal)
## load data
setwd("C:\\...")
SS_data <- read.csv2("Coordinates.csv",header=TRUE)
#WL.shp file
shp.greenland<-readOGR("C:\\Users\\Andreas\\SkyDrive\\Speciale\\02. Data\\02. Statistik","WL")
## NG.shp file
shp.greenland<-readOGR("C:\\Users\\Andreas\\SkyDrive\\Speciale\\02. Data\\02. Statistik","NG")
## cordinates
Y=SS_data[,"Latitude"]
X=SS_data[,"Longitude"]

el=SS_data[,"Xx"]
## Create pdf
pdf("Au dot plot.pdf",width=50,height=20,onefile=F)
## plot map with x,y coordinates
plot(X,Y,frame.plot=FALSE,xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="",type="n")
plot(shp.greenland)#, col="grey")

# take symbols continuously growing
q=c(min(el),min(el)+(max(el)-min(el))/2,max(el))

# symbols and size
symb=c(16,16,16)
ssize=c(5,10,20)

# plot symbols:
el01=(el-min(el))/(max(el)-min(el))
el01ssize=el01*(ssize[3]-ssize[1])+ssize[1]
points(X, Y, pch=symb[3], cex=el01ssize, col="red")

#Legend
legn=round(q,2)
leg=rep(NA,length(q))
for (i in 1:length(q)){
  leg[i]=roundpretty(legn[i],2)
}
legend("topright",pch=rev(symb),pt.cex=rev(ssize), legend=rev(leg), title=paste("La ppm"),
       cex=8, col="red")
dev.off()
```

Comment: One is UTM and one is long/lat. The plotting does not automatically transform one to another (alas).

Comment: Great. Apparently MapInfo needs more precise instructions to make it Lat/Lon than I gave it! Thanks :-)

Comment: Your link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in your shapefiles is that the first shapefile is in **UTM** coordinates and the second is in **lat/lon** coordinates.

Comment: Copy of a comment given 5 months ago.

Comment: And in all those months, the commenter never wrote it up as an answer. If dimitris' answer gets this off the unanswered list, he deserves the credit.